# How to iterate array elements inside a filehandle loop in perl

Tags: perl

Here is what I have:

```
open INFILE,    "<",    "$inputfile";
open OUTFILE,   ">",    "$outfile";
@array = qw{ Element1 Element2 };
        if ( ! open INFILE, "<", "$inputfile") {
                die "Cannot open INFILE: $!";
        }
while (<INFILE>) {
         if ($_ =~ m/(str1)|(str2)/sg) {
              chomp;
              $regex = $_;
                   foreach $list (@array) {
                            print OUTFILE "\$list is $list\n";
                            print OUTFILE "String is $regex\n";
                    }
          }
}

close INFILE;
close OUTFILE;
```

What I am getting is:

```
\$list is ELEMENT 1
String is str1
\$list is ELEMENT 2
String is str1
\$list is ELEMENT 3
String is str1
```

I want this output:

```
\$list is ELEMENT 1
String is str1
\$list is ELEMENT 2
String is str2
\$list is ELEMENT 3
String is str3
```

Comment: `"$var"` is cargo cult programming. there is not point in creating a new string, embedding a variable in it, when the variable by itself would do just as well.

Comment: `@array` should be declared as `@array = qw( )`. Why do you open `INFILE` twice?

Comment: Okay I modified my script but I am still having some issues. I will post it.

Comment: There is no way you are getting that output. `@array` contains `"Element1", "Element2"` and that could never (with this code) become `ELEMENT 1` through `ELEMENT 3`. Furthermore, how do you expect us to be able to know why it prints `str1` when we don't know what your input is?

Comment: This is outside the loop $regex = $_; So while you are looping through your element array you are not changing the $regex

Comment: Is there anyway to iterate each value of an array besides foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that should be used at the top of every script:

```
use warnings; use 5.012; # (or whatever version you are using)
```

If you `use` a version greater than `5.010`, you get all sorts of goodies like automatic `strict`ness and the `say` function.

It is dangerous to go alone. Take error handling with you:

```
open my $filehandle, "<", $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
```

Using `open` without `die` is likely to be an invitation for bugs.

I would code your `while`-loop as:

```
while (my $line = <$infile>) {
  chomp $line;
  if ($line =~ /str[12]/) {
    foreach my $element (@array) {
      say $outfile "I am at element $element";
      say $outfile "The string is $line";
    }
  }
}
```

This ↑ is a bit beautified and streamlined, but equivalent to what you wrote in your post. If your files are small, you could even do a

```
foreach my $line (grep {chomp; /str[12]/} <$infile>) {
  foreach my $element (@array) {...}
}
```

Now that we have reasonably clean code, we can think about your issues:

The code you gave does not produce the output you claim it does: Neither does `@array` contain an `ELEMENT 3`, nor is your regex able to match `str3`. Also, for each matched string, you print the contents for *all* elements in `@array`. `print "\$"` prints `$` and not `\$`.

I shall assume that you want to match `str` followed by a single digit, and that you want to choose that element from the `@array` that is at the corresponding position.

```
# selecting the lines
my @lines;
while (<$infile>) {
  chomp;
  push @lines, [$_ => $1-1] if /str(\d)/ and $1 > 0; # avoid off-by-one errors
  # push @lines, [$1 => $2-1] if /(str(\d))/ and $2 > 0;
}

# clever initialization
my @array = map {"ELEMENT $_"} 1..9;

# print out the report
foreach my $line (@lines) {
  my ($string, $index) = @$line;
  my $element = $array[$index];
  say $outfile "I have $element";
  say $outfile "String is $string";
}
# folding the loops into one is left as an exercise for the reader
```

Now if the input is

```
str1
str2
foo
str3
Here is str8 among other things!
bar
str45
baz
```

The output will be

```
I have ELEMENT 1
String is str1
I have ELEMENT 2
String is str2
I have ELEMENT 3
String is str3
I have ELEMENT 8
String is Here is str8 among other things!
I have ELEMENT 4
String is str45
```